# Prevent the <a> tag to fire, when clicking a child video element without affecting video controls

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-click-event

I have this gallery of photos and videos that is fetched from social networks via a hashtag search. And this is the **HTML** structure:

```
<div class="media-holder">
<a href="--mediaURL here---">
   <div class="description-bar></div>


// CODE HERE TO CHECK IF ITS A VIDEO OR AN IMAGE
// LET'S SAY NOW ITS A VIDEO

   <div class="media">
      <video> ... </video>
   </div>
</a>
</div>
```

Now, my problem is whenever I click the play button of the video, the parent `<a>` tag fires its target link. I am trying to prevent that only on the video tag so whenever the user clicks on the video it would just play and wouldn't open the link and if I click on the `description-bar div`, I want the `<a>` tag to fire the target link.

I have tried using `jQuery event.stopPropagation()`

```
$('.media-holder video').click(function(e){
    ...
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

but this also affects the video controls.

Other facts:
If the result media is an image, I want the `<a>` tag to function naturally.

Comment: try e.stopImmediatePropagation()

Comment: *bang!* You were fired by `a tag`

Comment: You may just try likeee, `e.preventDefault()`. Just like Andy told you so.

Comment: Exactly when is the link suppose to fire? The link should only wrap the content that is part of the link and normally is not wrapped around blocks.

Comment: Edited my question, I need also the <a> tag to fire when I click on the desc-bar whatever the content is.

Comment: Is the image a fallback and that HTML appears wrapped in the video tag?

Comment: Yes, the html inside the <div class="media"> depends if the fetched media is an image type or video type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy literal answer to the question is to turn on the link via javascript. A link can not change the href unless the href exists. In other words it can not fire.

Note: there are alternative ways to pass a click from a top layer to the layer underneath in a layered presentation. But in that case the HTML would be different than what you are showing.

```
<div class="media-holder">
<a id="mylink" name="--mediaURL here---">
   <div class="description-bar></div>


// CODE HERE TO CHECK IF ITS A VIDEO OR AN IMAGE
// LET'S SAY NOW ITS A VIDEO

   <div class="media">
      <video> ... </video>
   </div>
</a>
</div>

<script> 
/* activate link */
document.getElementById("mylink").href=document.getElementById("mylink").name;
<script>
```

However, an image does not appear in the html given. A fallback would look like this.

```
<div class="media">
  <video>
    <a href="--meidaURL here--"><img src="imageURL here"></a>
  </video>
</div>
```

And the proper format for the link on the description bar

```
<div class="description-bar>
   <a id="mylink" name="--mediaURL here---">something here</a>
</div>
```

A non-proper link on the descript bar may cause side effects like the link overlaying a menu which is all the way on the side, or the link firing when one clicks near the description within the margins of the block but not on the description itself.

Comment: @reuelab that would be the best approach.

Comment: though I need to repeat the <a> tags, It's perfectly working now for what I intended to happen.. Thanks for this!